# How can I perform chaincode from user interface in my bank app developed with hyperledger fabric and golang backend, and react js frontend?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to develop a simple bank app using Hyperledger Fabric (backend in Golang) and create my front end in React.js so if there is any sample for this project please do guide me as I'm new in this field. All the respected experts are requested to help me.

I have installed Hyperledger Fabric and deployed Chaincode (Smart Contract) for my Bank App, now I don't know what to do for performing the Chaincode from user interface.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up the backend:

   - Define API in Go to handle user requests and
     interact with Chaincode
   - Write Go based Chaincode for account-creation, fund-transfer, balance-retrieval
2. Frontend-Backend Connection:

   - Make Http requests from the Frontend to Backend
   - Make React components and UI elements for account-details, transaction-amounts
3. API request in Backend:

   - Parse incoming request in Go and validate user input
   - Retrieve response from Chaincode and send Http response back to Frontend
4. React.js Frontend:

   - Based on backend response, display appropriate messages on UI
   - Refresh UI to show updated account balance and transaction history